# How to check if image is already exist in photo album during saving the image in photo album

Tags: iphone

I would like to save image into photo album and at the same time i want to check the same image is already present over there or not.

If it is there already i have to give alert message stated that image is already exist or Saved successfully if it is new.

Comment: How do you want to determine if the same image already exists? Just by file name?

Comment: @jamone Can some one please answer this question i am facing same problem.